# Curectly save OneToMany entity if parent has not ID

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many, spring-repositories

I have 2 entities:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString(exclude = "products")
@Entity
@Table(name = "categories")
public class Category {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;
  private String categoryName;
  private String categoryType;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Product> products;
}
```

and second entity:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;
  private String productName;
  private String productDescription;
  @ManyToOne()
  private Category category;
}
```

And I have 2 repository for each entity:

```
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {
}

@Repository
public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Category, Long> {
}
```

Then I send this JSON to cintroller and I heed save all Product:

```
{
    "products": [{
        "productName": "product1",
        "productDescription": "productDescription1",
        "category": {
            "categoryName": "catName1",
            "categoryType": "type1"
        }
    },
    {
        "productName": "product2",
        "productDescription": "productDescription2",
        "category": {
            "categoryName": "catName1",
            "categoryType": "type1"
        }
    },
    {
        "productName": "product3",
        "productDescription": "productDescription3",
        "category": {
            "categoryName": "catName2",
            "categoryType": "type2"
        }
    }]
}
```

And Then I need save it:

```
@PostMapping(value = "test")
public Category test(@RequestBody() RequestTest products) {

  List<Product> productList = products.getProducts();
  for (Product product : productList) {
  //save all
  }
}
```

category not have id and when I get this JSON I need create all products and set category, but I have not category id and if I do next:

```
for (Product product : productList) {
      Category category = product.getCategory();
      Category save = categoryRepository.save(category);
      product.setCategory(save);
      productRepository.save(product);
}
```

I create new ctegore for each product and I get  this:

```
49  catName1    type1
51  catName1    type1
53  catName2    type2
                                        cat_id
50  productDescription1 product1        49
52  productDescription2 product2        51
54  productDescription3 product3        53
```

but I need:

```
49  catName1    type1
51  catName2    type2
                                        cat_id
50  productDescription1 product1        49  
52  productDescription2 product2        49  
54  productDescription3 product3        51
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to find first if the category object already exists.

You could create a query that searches if a category exists by the same name and type. If it exists, use that object, which will have the ID too, or else go on with your current code.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the best way would be to keep track of saved categories by introducing a Map.

Assuming that `categoryName` is a unique column then you could do something following:

```
Map<String,Category> categoryMap = new HashMap<>();

for (Product product : productList) {
      String categoryName = product.getCategory().getCategoryName(); 
      Category category = categoryMap.get(categoryName);

      if(category == null){
         category = categoryRepository.save(product.getCategory());
         categoryMap.put(categoryName,category);
      }       

      product.setCategory(save);
      productRepository.save(product);
}
```

Comment: You could also try categoryRepository.findByCategoryName instead of the map. Thats a search not by id though so the persisteence context might be skipped.

Comment: Yes, I do. specify what it means "so the persisteence context might be skipped."?

Comment: when you save.. there is not insert to the database.. that happens after transaction is commited. when you query by id the persistence provider goes to the persistence context first to see if there are any entities caches there.. if its not by id.. it might got to the database.. where there is no entry yet. Give it a try though

Answer (score 0):

First insert all the unique categories and check for same exist in database.
Make sure categories should be unique.